# Scala Play 2 Framework: PrivilegedActionException: null

Tags: scala, exception, playframework-2.0, slick

So, i study play 2 framework + slick. code is simple query to db with slick. And get exception. And I don't understand what to do.

my controller:

```
class IndexController @Inject()(taskRepo: TaskRepo) extends Controller {
  def index = Action.async { implicit rs =>
    taskRepo.all().map(tasks => Ok(views.html.index(tasks)))
  }
}
```

and exception:

```
[info] ! @6pp163f7m - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->
[info]  
[info] play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[PrivilegedActionException: null]]
[info]  at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:269)
[info]  at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:195)
[info]  at play.core.server.Server$class.logExceptionAndGetResult$1(Server.scala:45)
[info]  at play.core.server.Server$class.getHandlerFor(Server.scala:65)
[info]  at play.core.server.NettyServer.getHandlerFor(NettyServer.scala:45)
[info]  at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler.handle(PlayRequestHandler.scala:81)
[info]  at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler.channelRead(PlayRequestHandler.scala:162)
[info]  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:307)
[info]  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:293)
[info]  at com.typesafe.netty.http.HttpStreamsHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsHandler.java:129)
[info] Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: null
[info]  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[info]  at play.runsupport.Reloader$.play$runsupport$Reloader$$withReloaderContextClassLoader(Reloader.scala:39)
[info]  at play.runsupport.Reloader.reload(Reloader.scala:336)
[info]  at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:118)
[info]  at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:116)
[info]  at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
[info]  at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
[info]  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
[info]  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
[info]  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
[info] Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [300000 milliseconds]
[info]  at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
[info]  at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
[info]  at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:190)
[info]  at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
[info]  at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:190)
[info]  at play.forkrun.ForkRun$$anonfun$askForReload$1.apply(ForkRun.scala:128)
[info]  at play.forkrun.ForkRun$$anonfun$askForReload$1.apply(ForkRun.scala:126)
[info]  at play.runsupport.Reloader$$anonfun$reload$1.apply(Reloader.scala:338)
[info]  at play.runsupport.Reloader$$anon$3.run(Reloader.scala:43)
[info]  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

what i do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Problem was in `Futures timed out after [300000 milliseconds]`

in `build.sbt` change `fork in run := true` to `fork in run := false`